# Can't modifiy eloquent query result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

So I got the following code in my controller's `show` function which just returns a page with the tags:

```
$page = Post::with('tags')->findOrFail($id);
$page->tags->lists('name');
return response($page);
```

When I try to to execute this, it won't change the `tags` key, which is an array with the tags from the eloquent `belongsToMany` relationship.

Why isn't this working? To me it seems pretty handy to just change a value like this.

When I change it to `$page->test = $page->tags->lists('name')` it will add the `test` key as usual.

How would I modify a eloquent value in a easy way?

Comment: which version is it `laravel-4` or `laravel-5` ?

Comment: @BrianDillingham I've modified the tag. Its laravel-5. Functionality is the same in laravel-4 though.

Comment: What do you mean by *it won't change the `tags` key*? Explain the result you get and the one you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

After the `$page = Post::with('tags')->findOrFail($id);` line is executed, `$page->tags` is going to be an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object containing all the related `Tag`s for the `Post`.  From your provided code and question, it sounds like you want to then change `$page->tags` to be an array containing just the related tag names.

The statement `$page->tags->lists('name')` is only going to return an array of all the names of the related tags; it does not modify the underlying collection. If you wanted to modify the `$page->tags` attribute, you would need to assign it the result of your statement:

```
$page->tags = $page->tags->lists('name');
```

However, `$page->tags` was an attribute that was dynamically created and assigned by the Model, and is expected to hold the contents of a relationship. Manually modifying the contents like this may have unintended consequences, but I do not know.

### Edit

The `Model::toArray()` method merges in the relationship information over the attribute information. So, you can change the attribute, but if you echo the model, the relationship information will show up over your attribute change.

```
$page->tags = $page->tags->lists('name');

// this will echo the tags attribute, which is now the array of tags
echo print_r($page->tags, true);

// this will echo the model, with the tags attribute being
// overwritten with the related data
echo $page;
```

One option would be to unset the attribute (which also unsets the relationship) and then reassign the attribute to your desired data:

```
$page = Post::with('tags')->findOrFail($id);
$temp = $page->tags;
unset($page->tags); // you must unset the attribute before reassigning it
$page->tags = $temp->lists('name');
return response($page);
```

A little bit cleaner would be to use a different attribute name:

```
$page = Post::with('tags')->findOrFail($id);
$page->tagNames = $page->tags->lists('name');
unset($page->tags);
return response($page);
```

And another option is to do what @lukasgeiter suggested and override the `Model::toArray` method:

```
class Post extends Model {
    public function toArray() {
        // call the parent functionality first
        $array = parent::toArray();
        if (isset($this->tags)) {
            $array['tags'] = $this->tags->lists('name');
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding it to the `$page->tags` won't work. For example `$page->tags = 'test';` is not modifying the value as well.

Comment: @guidsen What exactly are you trying to modify? If you do `$page->tags = 'test'; echo $page->tags;`, it will echo out 'test' (L4.1).  This will not actually modify any of the tag information, though. So, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im using laravel as webservice and on my page entity i dont care about all the tag information which the eloquent relationship provides me. I just want to return an array containing the tagnames.

Comment: Mind that `$page->tags = $page->tags->lists('name');` is going to add another attribute to the model, not replace the `tags` relation.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Yeah, that's what I tried to get across with my update.  That's why you would need to `unset($page->tags)` before assigning it a value, because the `unset` will clear out both the attribute and the relation.

Answer (score 0):

What works pretty well for such cases is overriding `toArray` in your Model:

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $array['tags'] = $this->tags->lists('name');
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: That's an option, but Eloquent provides better/more expressive way - check my answer.

Comment: Sure, except that with your solution the name changes. Maybe that's not a big deal but it would bother me...

Comment: The name changes on purpose and may not be changed. In fact I wouldn't do that anyway, since that's more of the `Tags` collection responsibility to decide how it should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the output of one of the relationships in the `toArray`/`toJson` methods, then use [**accessor**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators):

```
// in order to not show the underlying collection:
protected $hidden = ['tags'];

// in order to append accessor to toArray output
protected $appends = ['allTags'];

// mutate the collection to be just an array of tag names
public function getAllTagsAttribute()
{
  $collection = return $this->getRelation('tags');
  return ($relation) ? $collection->lists('name') : [];
}
```

then you will get simple array instead of collection when you do `$page->allTags` or in the `toArray`/`toJson` output, while not showing the real collection.

It is `allTags` not `tags, since the latter should remain eloquent dynamic property, so you can work with it as usual before outputting anything.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps. To be honest, I do not get your point. But I guess there is something wrong with this line:
`$page->tags->lists('name');`
If `$page->tags` is a `belongsToMany` relationship and you want to add more query conditions after this relationship, you should query like this:
`$page->tags()->lists('name');`